# ace editor non capturing group issue (?:)

Tags: javascript, regex, editor, ace-editor, regex-lookarounds

All,

I'm trying to create my own mode with the ACE editor . I'm trying to define a really simple syntax highlighting rule:

```
this.$rules = {
    "start": [
        {
            token : "string", 
            regex : /(?:CONSUME)(MATCH)/,
        }
    ]
};
```

According to an online Javascript regular expression tester, the regex /(?:CONSUME)(MATCH)/ should see CONSUMEMATCH and return only MATCH. However, ACE highlights all of CONSUMEMATCH with this rule.

Plug the following code into the Ace Mode Creator (http://ace.c9.io/tool/mode_creator.html) to see for yourself.

(In the dropdown menus, I have the Javascript mode and the XCode theme selected. CONSUMEMATCH is my test text, and the following code is the contents of the mode panel.)

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

var oop = require("../lib/oop");
var TextHighlightRules = require("./text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

var myHighlightRules = function() {

    this.$rules = {
        "start": [
            {
                token : "string", 
                regex : /(?:CONSUME)(MATCH)/,
            }
        ]
    };
};

oop.inherits(myHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);
exports.myHighlightRules = myHighlightRules;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since js regexps do not provide a way to determine position of matched group in string, Ace only supports regexps with all matching or all non-matching groups. Try using

```
{
    token : ["text", "string"], 
    regex : /(CONSUME)(MATCH)/,
}
```

instead.

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly useful. Thanks! I've seen the array notation for tokens in code, but I couldn't find any explanation. Separate issue: is there a place that clearly explains what "states" like start and no_regex mean, along with the purpose of "next" (sometimes used alongside "token" and "regex" when specifying rules)? I find ace's documentation cryptic and unsatisfying.

Comment: Also, ace doesn't seem to recognize modifier flags like "i". If I try to write a case insensitive regex for a rule, such as /RULE/i, ace will catch RULE but not RuLe.

Comment: case sensitivity can be specified only for whole state, add rule `{caseInsensitive: true}`

Comment: Ace highlight rules creates state machine next is the name of next state no_regex means / will be division instead of regex, start is the first state of the state machine. About documentation i know only of http://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode#highlighter-rules and this old one http://pcwalton.blogspot.com/2010/11/syntax-highlighting-specification.html. If you do not find answers to your questions in these, ask a new question, long comments are not allowed on stackoverflow

Comment: Awesome, that worked for me too. What about clearer API documentation than at http://ace.c9.io/? For example, the page on extending syntax highlighters says "The syntax highlighting state machine stays in the start state, until you define a next state for it to advance to. At that point, the tokenizer stays in that new state, until it advances to another state. Afterwards, you should return to the original start state." What actually causes the tokenizer to advance from state to state? I still don't know how states work or what they're for.

Comment: tokenizer changes state when rule with `next` matches. I can't add long code examples in comment to explain better.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry about the repeat questioning, we must have been writing our responses at the same time.

Comment: This is great. Thank you.